# PostgreSQL COALESCE function returns Null even though value exists

Tags: postgresql

I've got the following table (nodes) in a PostgreSQL DB
and I'm looking to extract either the http OR https information. I am using COALESCE.

```
SELECT COALESCE(http,https) 
FROM oig.nodes 
WHERE owner_name = %s 
  AND node_type = COALESCE('full','api')
```

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      owner          |     node_type    |       http       |      https       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          test123    |         full     | http://1.1.1.1   |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          testabc    |         api      |                  | http://1.1.1.2   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          testabc    |         seed     |                  |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

This works, but only if the node_type = full, if the node_type = api, it returns None.

Comment: Make sure you have `NULL`s not empty '' string

Comment: Maybe it's not a null value, but an empty string (`''`). Try `nullif(http_node_url, '')`

Comment: I check definitely is NULL value.  I forgot to mention that there could be two or more owners with the same name.

Comment: As you see now, "it returns None" is a bit vague. We thought that you get a result row in which the value is null. Now it seems you are not getting any row at all. Always describe what happens very precisely, so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 2):

`COALESCE('full','api')` is equivalent to `'full'` because `'full'` is definitely not null.

Comment: yes works if owner = test123, but if owner = testabc, it returns None.

Comment: because none row matches AND condition. Didn't you rather mean `AND node_type in ('full','api')`?

Comment: just tried that and same issue - SELECT COALESCE(http_node_url,https_node_url),owner_name FROM oig.nodes WHERE owner_name = %s AND node_type in ('full','api')

Comment: weird... `in` can be broken to two expressions separated by `OR`. Perhaps some whitespace or parenthesising issue... (may be try to extract it to selfstanding query, your column names don't match those in your ascii-art table)

Comment: When I try SELECT COALESCE(http_node_url,https_node_url),owner_name FROM oig.nodes WHERE owner_name = %s AND node_type = 'full' OR  node_type = 'api' - it then only returns the first row from the table no matter what owner_)name I pass.

Comment: `WHERE owner_name = %s AND node_type = 'full' OR node_type = 'api'` translates to `WHERE (owner_name = %s AND node_type = 'full') OR node_type = 'api'`. It should return all 'api' rows hence (plus the requested owner in case its type is 'full').

Comment: @Ankh2054: Tomáš has shown you what you did wrong in your query. Now it seems that adding to this, the data in the table is not to be what you think it is. Examine this step by step. `select * from oig.nodes where node_type = 'full';`. `select * from oig.nodes where node_type = 'api';`. `select node_type, length(node_type), count(*) from oig.nodes group by node_type;`...

Comment: thanks for all the help - this worked in the end - SELECT COALESCE(http_node_url,https_node_url) FROM oig.nodes WHERE owner_name = %s AND (node_type = 'api' OR node_type = 'full')